# R gt() summary table: problems when "Knit to tufte_handout"

Tags: r, gt

I've produced a gt() table with sub-total rows and it looks great until i knit it to tufte_handout. Let me show you. This is an excerpt of the table in html:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrjY9.png)

But when i knit to tufte_handout, the sub-totals go to a new line and in their places i get horizontal lines, like in the next picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43QHr.png)

Does anyone know why this is happening? How can i fix it?

This is the code i'm using:

```
---
title: "stuff - ppt"
date: "04/08/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
    dev: CairoPNG
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 16
    fig_width: 20
--- 


tib <- tibble(Categ = c("A","B","C","B","B","C","A","A","A"),
              Subcateg=c("A1","B1","C2","B2","B3","C2","A1","A1","A3"),
              Id=c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH","II"))

tib %>%
  count(Subcateg, Categ) %>%
  mutate(prop = round((n / sum(n)) * 100, 2)) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "Subcateg", groupname_col = "Categ")  %>% 
  summary_rows(
    groups = TRUE,
    columns = vars(n, prop),
    fns = list(total = ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE))
  ) %>% 
  summary_rows(
    groups = TRUE,
    columns = vars(n),
    fns = list(total = ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)),
    formatter = fmt_number,
    decimals = 0) %>% 
  tab_options(
    row_group.font.weight = "bold"
  ) %>% 
  
  cols_label(
    Subcateg = "Classification",
    n = "Frequency",
    prop = "Percentage"
  ) %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "Number of stuff",
    columns = vars(n, prop)
  ) %>%
  tab_header(
    title = "Classification",
    subtitle = md("&nbsp;")
  )  %>% 
  as_latex()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your yaml header look like? Can you upload the entire file to see how you have your tufte file set up

Comment: @Daniel Jachetta, i've added the header to my example code.
Thanks!